# Calculating REM for elements other than font-size

Tags: css, padding, margin

```
#sign-up-cta .striking {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
}
```

If we use `rem` for `padding` or `margin`, where is it taking the default values from? Then if we do declare `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` then where is it taking the value from?

The example above `.75rem` is for the position of the text. What would `.75rem` be if we don't declare `padding` or `margin`?

Comment: it takes it from the html tag

Comment: What makes you think margin or padding had _anything_ to do with what 1rem is in the first place?

Comment: REM is from the root element (html). EM get its value from the parent element.

Comment: @CBroe I have a project that I am trying to complete now and there are a lot of things other than font-size that are using REM. I read an article that said REM can cause issues if you use it everywhere. As far as I know I am seeing that we should only use it with font-size and use % or px with other elements.

Comment: @Dejan.S That's what I have learned. I was confused as to why this project has so many elements in REM. I was curious about the default values of html. I know 16px is supposed to be the default for font-size, but what's the default for everything else.

Comment: _"we should only use it with font-size and use % or px with other elements"_ - well that entirely depends on whether you want margins/paddings to be related to the font size, or the width of the containing block ... there's surely applications for both, a general "never do X" makes rather little sense in that regard.

Comment: _"but what's the default for everything else"_ - for _what_ else? If you have margin/padding/any other length specified in `rem` - then that relates to the font-size of the root element as well.

Answer (score 0):

The rem unit is equal to the font-size of the html element, which you can define in your project or is defined by the user's browser settings. The default value in all browsers is 16px (as far as I know).

Rem is used if you want to use the same unit anywhere in your project while still having a responsive design by accomodating to the user's custom set browser font-size.

Comment: That's what I have learned and it seems that the best practice is to use rem for font-size only and everything else with % and px. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @webdevtonym I hope you didn't read my post as REM is only good for font-size. My point was that if you have 1rem and your html tag has `font-size: 18;` 1rem = 18px. Regarding your comment about % and px, no not really, not at all. Rem should be used for all instances except for a few, like borders (px). PX is not good to use because it's a fixed value and not responsive to something like browser zoom. % is in my opinion an old way of doing responsive design before flex and grid.

Comment: @webdevtonym This is not what I meant. You can generally use rem for everything you want a uniform unit for. Let's say you have two buttons in two differently sized containers. If you used `em` or `%` for the size of the buttons, you could get two differently sized buttons. `%` is relative to the parent's size and `em` is relative to the element's font size. That is why you use `rem`, so you can size objects by the same unit (`1 rem = 16px` by default). It is recommended to avoid using `px`

Comment: @Dejan.S What do you mean by px is not responsive to browser zoom? Look at [this](http://www.mcom.com/home/welcome.html). I'm pretty sure this is marked up using px and it zooms just fine. Also I think stack overflow is using px, as changing the browser font size doesn't change the website scaling.

Comment: @NHerwich Sure the browsers did get better at that (btw the link use em as measure unit). Still most cases building a website today (actually 5-6 years back) is using relative units, and there are more new units coming. It's not uncommon that sites have a larger font-size for a larger screen, if you set your margins/paddings in rem that will scale with it and you don't have to change anything, if you set px it won't. [smashingmagazine.com](http://smashingmagazine.com/) is a great example, [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com).

Comment: @Dejan.S How did you find out the website I linked uses em? In the markup I can't find any unit used. By default html uses px, right?

Comment: @NHerwich I checked in devtools. The em is set default for specific elements by the browser, in this specific case it was for <p> <hr>, so the value for that is gone be dependent on parent font-size. Regarding HTML having units, the browsers have default units to what make sense for specific elements, so it's not default px.